# Need help to complete installation of linter-stylelint for Atom

Tags: stylelint, linter

I am really sorry for this newbie question but I can't see how solve that...

I installed linter-stylelint and tried to configure it like it's said there:
https://atom.io/packages/linter-stylelint

So:
- I placed a stylelint.config.js file in my project.
- In the settings, I checked Use standard 
- But can't see what I have to do to "Add a stylelint section in your package.json"

On my Mac I see the file:
/Users/eric/node_modules/stylelint-config-standard
But I don't know what code do I have to insert inside...

By the way, when I try to use linter-stylelint in a css file I get the error message:
Unable to parse stylelint configuration
Unexpected token :

In my stylelint.config.js, I have the following code for now:

```
{
"extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
  "rules" {
    "no-unsupported-browser-features": [ true, { "severity": "warning" }]
   }
}
```

Thanks if you can help me!
;)

Paul

Answer (score 0):

> So: - I placed a stylelint.config.js file in my project. - In the settings, I checked Use standard

According to [the docs you reference](https://atom.io/packages/linter-stylelint#configuration), you should *either* place a `stylelint.config.js` file *or* check "Use standard".

> I get the error message `Unable to parse stylelint configuration Unexpected token :`

This is because the JSON of your configuration file is invalid. It is missing both a comma and a colon. Use a service like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON. Your fixed config is:

```
{
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "rules": {
        "no-unsupported-browser-features": [true, {
            "severity": "warning"
        }]
    }
}
```

Even though this config is valid JSON, it won't work because the `no-unsupported-browser-features` rule is no longer built into stylelint. It is, however, available as a plugin. You'll need to follow [the plugin's instructions](https://github.com/ismay/stylelint-no-unsupported-browser-features) if you wish to use it.

> I am really sorry for this newbie question

It's fine. We are all newbies in the beginning! As you're just getting started with stylelint, I suggest you remove the `stylelint.config.js` file and ensure the "Use Standard" box is checked. This is likely the quickest way to get going. Once you are more comfortable with the tool, you can investigate [creating your own configuration](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md) file for your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks!
Now I can:
- use standard csslint
- use extended with this code
//.stylelintrc
{
    "extends": "/Users/eric/node_modules/stylelint-config-standard",
    "plugins": [
    "/Users/eric/node_modules/stylelint-no-unsupported-browser-features"
  ],
    "rules": {
        "plugin/no-unsupported-browser-features": [true, {
            "severity": "warning"
        }]
    }
}
But few Errors became Warnings…
- How could I configure .stylelintrc to mark « minor stylistic » errors as warnings?
- Any tool to format stylesheets for the « minor stylistic » errors?

Comment: pfff... unable to format code...
`code`//.stylelintrc
{
    "extends": "/Users/eric/node_modules/stylelint-config-standard",
    "plugins": [
    "/Users/eric/node_modules/stylelint-no-unsupported-browser-features"
  ],
    "rules": {
        "plugin/no-unsupported-browser-features": [true, {
            "severity": "warning"
        }]
    }
}